# Cython file write

Tags: cython

- I have a sample '.pyx' file
- Here, certain mmap operation has been done (via C mmap) and the  and 'data_len' has been returned
- I want to read from the offset start upto the data_len area, AND dump it to a random file

I am doing this by the following: BUT, getting Syntax error while doing 'write' operation

```
cdef void *startmmaparea
def do_dump() 
    offset= <char *> startmmaparea
...
    with open('abc.bin','wb') as fdes:
     fdes.write(offset.read(data_len))  
...
```

expected to write the mmap content to the file. but getting Syntax error in the 'write' op
Can I write the  using the read() as I have done above ?
- Can anyone help me with what I am doing wrong here ?

Comment: You should include [mcve] and the exact error message

Comment: it is just showing 'Syntax error in simple include statement: <Line_no>'....the error is not indicative enough and hence was not mentioned

Comment: You don't isn't include statements in the code shown, hence the problem is with an error message that you aren't showing us in some code that you aren't showing us! In the code here, `offset` is just a C character pointer, so has no member functions (`offset.read`?)

Comment: Just to clarify my mistyped comment: the code you show doesn't have any "include" statements so I think the error is coming from code you don't show